# How to express the Pythons' NumPy linspace or arange arrays mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

How one can express digital one dimensional array, such as `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)` or `x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)` (examples taken from Python) mathematically? To be more specific, say one have the range expressed as `x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)`, which gives:

```
[ -1  -9.00000000e-01  -8.00000000e-01  -7.00000000e-01
  -6.00000000e-01  -5.00000000e-01  -4.00000000e-01  -3.00000000e-01
  -2.00000000e-01  -1.00000000e-01  -2.22044605e-16   1.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01   3.00000000e-01   4.00000000e-01   5.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01   7.00000000e-01   8.00000000e-01   9.00000000e-01]
```

How can I write it down mathematically as a short description of, say, set? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A partition of [-1,0.9] in 19 equally spaced subintervals?

Comment: I know that, but how one can write it down mathematically?

Comment: I would know of no tasteful mathematical operation that would produce something containing the number $-2.22044605\times10^{-16}$ from your input. (But computers are bound to do tasteless things now and then.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the set of all reals $r$ (I will ignore the difference between reals and floats here - not that it is unimportant), where $r=-1+0.1\times n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r\ge -1$ and $r\lt 1$, or (not quite fully formally):
$$
x=\{r: r=-1+0.1\times n\ , \ \ n\in \{0,1, \dots 19 \} \}
$$

or:

$$
x=\{r: \exists  n\in \mathbb{N}\text{ such that } r=-1+0.1\times n\ , \text{ and }  r \in [-1,1) \} \}
$$

or any other of a large number of ways of expressing it.